# hadoop: limit number of concurrent map / reduce tasks per job

Tags: hadoop

I want to submit a research job into a production cluster. As I don't need this job to finish quickly, and I don't want to delay production jobs, I want to limit the number of tasks that are executing for that job at any given time. Can I do that in Hadoop 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For limiting the Hadoop mapreduce resources (map/reduce slots) **Fair scheduler** can be used. You better create a new fairscheduler pool by setting up desired number of maximum mappers and maximum reducers and job can be submitted to that newly created fairscheduler pool.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do the following

1. job.getConfiguration().setInt("mapred.map.tasks", 1);
2. job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
3. job.setPriority(JobPriority.VERY_LOW);

Comment: Does the first setting mapred.map.tasks work even if multiple splits of input data are present or of multiple files are provided?

Comment: Assuming you have set mapred.map.tasks=1, it would makes sure that only 1 map instance of the job runs at a time.

Comment: Default value is 2. But running any jobs does not restrict no. of mappers to 2 does it? It does not in my case.

Comment: Incase you are running in pseudo distribution mode, it would be ignored. Basically the value is ignored if mapreduce.jobtracker.address is "local".